# Javascript .on('click' is not working on span

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, wagtail

So I've spend already 2 days trying to solve this.
I have a `<span class="faicon-add" data-id="id_object_places_proximity_keys-0-place_icon" rel="faicon-add">` and a jquery script loaded

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var icon_field = null;
    $( '<div id="faicon-modal-cont"></div>' ).appendTo( "body" );
    $( "#faicon-modal-cont" ).load( "/faicon/render_icon_list_modal/" ,function() {

        function close_over() {
            $('.faicon-screen').removeClass('show');
            $('body').removeClass('faicon-active');
        }

        $('.faicon-add').on('click', function(){
            $('body').addClass('faicon-active');
            $('.faicon-screen').addClass('show');
            icon_field = $('#'+$(this).data('id'));
        })

        $('.faicon-screen .close').on('click', function(){
            close_over();
        })

        $('.faicon-screen .list li').on('click', function(){
            var i = $(this).find('i');
            var i_parts = $(i).attr('class').split(' ');
            icon_field.val($(i).data('icon'));
            icon_field.siblings('.icon')
                .html('<i class="'+i_parts[0]+' '+i_parts[1]+' fa-3x"><i>');
            icon_field.siblings('[rel="faicon-add"]').hide();
            icon_field.siblings('.faicon-delete').show();
            close_over();
        })
    });
});
```

**The problem is that `$('.faicon-add').on('click', function(){` won't trigger...**

I've tried to add `onclick="open_modal();"` and directly placing this function under that `span`

```
<script>
function open_modal() {
    $('body').addClass('faicon-active');
    $('.faicon-screen').addClass('show');
    icon_field = $('#'+$(this).data('id'));
}
</script>
```

And it worked, but that is not a solution for me, because I need to give a modal that `icon_field` variable...

**Also** I tried to add only `$('.faicon-add').on('click', function(){` function in the Google DevTools console. Then when I click on span, modal is showing up... That's weird...

I've also tried to load script containing also only `$('.faicon-add').on('click', function(){` function, but inside it I've put only `alert('hello')`. That didn't work...

It's not a CSS issue, I've added `z-index:1000;pointer-events:all;` to that span and it's still won't work, even in DevTools console if I run `$('span.faicon-add')[1].click()` it's not working... (`[1]` because there's another span tag with class `faicon-add`)

Jquery is the latest version.

This `django-faicon` is supposed to work in django admin not in a wagtail admin interface. In django admin it works just as expected, so I think it's it a script intersection issue...

The only thing showing up in the console is `Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.`

And another **weird** thing is that all other functions work, for example if I manually add `show` class to `.faicon-screen` and then click on `.faicon-screen .close`, function runs as expected. So `$('.faicon-add').on('click', function(){` is not working in that script, which I can't determine why ONLY that function wont run! Maybe I can somehow insure that function is loaded? Help, please!

Comment: Try `$(document).on('click', '.faicon-add', function(){})`.

Comment: @hev1 HUGE THANKS! I don't know why this worked... But again, thank you!! Post an answer so I marked this issue solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use event delegation for dynamically added elements.

```
$(document).on('click', '.faicon-add', function(){})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly working, check the JQuery version

```html
<html>
   <body style="background-color: #f4f7fa;">
      <span class="faicon-add" data-id="id_object_places_proximity_keys-0-place_icon" rel="faicon-add">something</span>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                  $('.faicon-add').on('click', function(e){
                     e.preventDefault();
                     alert("hello");
                  })
            });
         </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the reply. Jquery version is 3.2.1 and I cant change it because wagtail doesn't allow that... I don't think it's the issue because `django-faicon` module requires Jquery 3.0.0